# PHP SimpleXML: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'

Tags: php, xml

I have this error when I am reading XML:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): feed.xml
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in  #1 {main} thrown
```

PHP:

```
$feed = new SimpleXMLElement("feed.xml");
echo $feed->SHOPITEM[0]->ID_PRODUCT;
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PRODUCTS>
  <SHOPITEM>
    <ID_PRODUCT><![CDATA[121110]]></ID_PRODUCT>
  </SHOPITEM>
  <SHOPITEM>
    <ID_PRODUCT><![CDATA[121111]]></ID_PRODUCT>
  </SHOPITEM>
</PRODUCTS>
```

Error is on the line where is `new SimpleXMLElement("feed.xml)` released. Where can be the problem? The XML file is valid.

Comment: I believe it is because `new SimpleXMLElement()` has to be a STRING. not a file name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

load the file like this

```
<?php

$feed = new SimpleXMLElement("xml.xml",null,true);
echo $feed->SHOPITEM[0]->ID_PRODUCT;
//prints 121110
```

see docs here http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php

> Use TRUE to specify that data is a path or URL to an XML document instead of string data.

Comment: Thank you very much, Alex!  :) I was so looking for syntax error that I passed a problem with loading.

Comment: I have the same issue!!

Comment: @AlexAndrei "some" explanation would be better instead of just the link to docs.